# Can I create a view of watchdog log entries?

Tags: views, log-messages

We want to view a more detailed view of watchdog log entries, filtered by module and level and showing the details section in a table. When creating a new view, watchdog logs is not in the list. Is there a way to do this like a Views3 plugin or something what would integrate this?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [Views Watchdog](http://drupal.org/project/views_watchdog)

> The Views Watchdog module extends the Views module and allows to create customized lists (pages, blocks, feeds) of watchdog entries.